# Use of passing arguments from derived class constructors to base class constructor

Tags: c++

Is it important to learn about calling the constructor of a base class in the constructor of a derived class?

What I mean is, is there any practical application of doing that? If yes, could someone provide me with an example and explain when to apply it and when not?

I just learned about it, and I don't know if it is used in actual applications.

Here is an example:

```
class base {
     int a;
     int b;
public:
     base(int i, int j) {
         a=i;
         b=j;
     }     
};

class derived : public base {
public:
     derived(int p, float q) : base(p, q)   //passing parameters to base class
     {  }
     };
```

Comment: Learning the basics of passing arguments is so easy that you can just start on it. Before you know it you've learned it. It only needs to have the barest minimum of practical utility for you to start teaching yourself this.

Comment: About 75-90% of the times I have a descendant class I call the base constructor, so yes, it's important :).

Comment: That example you gave requires `derived` to call the `base` constructor with explicit parameters because `base` has no default constructor. You answered your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I mean is, is there any practical application of doing that?

Yes. The number of use cases is too many to list here.

> If yes, could someone provide me with an example and explain when to apply it and when not?

Here are couple of examples when to apply it.

**Example 1:**

```
struct Rectangle
{
   Rectangle(int w, int h) : width(w), height(h) {}
   int width;
   int height;
};

struct Square : Rectangle
{
   Square(int size) : Rectangle(size, size) {}
};
```

**Example 2:**

```
struct Employee
{
   Employee(std::string const& name, int id) : name(name), id(id) {}
   std::string name;
   int id;
};

struct Manager : struct Employee
{
   Manager(std::string const& name, int id) : Emplyee(name, id) {}
   void addEmployee(int id)
   {
       managedEmployeeIDs.insert(id);
   }

   std::set<int> managedEmployeeIDs;
};
```

It's difficult to suggest where it is not appropriate because there are so many ways it can be inappropriate. It will be easier to tell when it is appropriate given an example.

Comment: thnxxx a lot friend ...i got it :)